# How to change Z index of addicional text in Item ( chart.js)

Tags: typescript, canvas, charts, html5-canvas, tooltip

I am adding additional elements to every item in my Chart

```
export const showAdditionalText: any = {
  afterDraw: (chart, easing) =>  {
    const ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset, i) => {
      const meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(i);

      meta.data.forEach((element, index) => {
        console.log(meta);
        if (meta.type === 'bubble') {
          const fontSize = 10;
          const fontStyle = 'normal';
          const fontFamily = 'Helvetica Neue';
          ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(fontSize, fontStyle, fontFamily);
          const dataString = dataset.data[index].projectNumber;
          ctx.textAlign = 'center';
          ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';


          ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
          const position = element.tooltipPosition();
          ctx.fillText(dataString, position.x, position.y - (fontSize / 4));

        }
      });
    });
  }
```

But when I hover tooltip does not overlap[image] this item

How can I change Z index of this new text and hide it under tooltip?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation

Comment: I thought that's what you're looking for, by setting the globalCompositeOperation you can decide to draw the new things under what you already have on the canvas